# hydrate Relay Fragment without Query

Tags: reactjs, graphql, relay, react-relay

In some parts of my app,
I have a component using a fragment.
but up the tree somewhere, i sometimes need to create temporary objects waiting to be synced with the server (once they will they are transformed as plain relay objects).

But until then, they are only a few objects passed down the tree of component.
The `createFragmentContainer` + some `@relay(mask: false)` make all this possible.
But I would like to make it a bit cleaner using `useFragment`.

Usefragment doesn't like at all the "fake fragment" data.

Is there a way to somewhat legibly hydrate a fragment from data not directly coming from a query?

or maybe another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best idea seems to go with commitLocalUpdate
you can even create new types for your need

https://relay.dev/docs/v10.1.3/mutations/#using-updater-and-optimisticupdater